# How to resolve timestamp code error in HIVE

Tags: sql, hive, impala

Need help here.

I have no issue to run below **2** codes in Impala however it appear error message when I run the same code in Hive.

Anyone could help to amend the code so that I able to run in HIVE.

Thank you.

`select  from_timestamp(to_timestamp(concat(from_timestamp(biz_dt,'yyyyMM'),'01'),'yyyyMMdd'),'yyyy-MM-dd') as first_day_of_mth from x_table`

`select from_timestamp(days_add(date_add(add_months(trunc(biz_dt,'MM'),1),-1),1), 'yyyy-MM-dd') as biz_dt1 from x_table`

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 approaches for Hive:

```
SELECT
  from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(concat(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(biz_dt, 'yyyyMMdd'), 'yyyy-MM'), '-01'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')) AS first_day_of_month
FROM x_table;

SELECT
 CONCAT(YEAR(biz_dt), '-', LPAD(MONTH(biz_dt), 2, '0'), '-01') as first_day_of_month
FROM x_table;
```

nb: both are untested

Comment: Hi @Paul Maxwell, 2nd code is working as expected.

Comment: I have 2nd code that need your help too, could you please try to resolve, thank you.

Comment: select from_timestamp(days_add(date_add(add_months(trunc(biz_dt,'MM'),1),-1),1), 'yyyy-MM-dd') as biz_dt1 from x_table

Comment: `SELECT date_format(date_add(concat(YEAR(biz_dt), '-', LPAD(MONTH(biz_dt) + 1, 2, '0'), '-01'), -1), 'yyyy-MM-dd') as biz_dt1
FROM x_table;`

Comment: Do you know how to "accept" an answer?  To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers   nb: this helps other users to know that the question does have an answer